# Cursing the Carriage?

Tags: ouran-high-school-host-club

What does Kaoru mean when he says "Cursed the Carriage" in episode 21 season 1? He said it was his private joke, but I think it has more meaning to it. Please answer with least spoilers as possible!

Comment: Are you talking about the bit near 21:30? He says "private joke" there (in the dub, blech), but I don't hear anything about "cursing" a carriage.

Comment: At what time mark did he say that? Listening to the Japanese raw, there's no "cursing" at the carriage at all?